# GPT damaged, two half-sized disks instead of one

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, gpt

I'm trying to help my father installing Gentoo instead of Windows on his new Acer Aspire S7 notebook.

However, we are experiencing issues to partition the 120GB SSD disk.

[`fdisk -l`](http://dpaste.com/1HGXB4F) tells us we have two 60GB disks instead of one 120GB disk.

Here is what `gdisk -l /dev/sd[ab]` tells us about [/dev/sda](http://dpaste.com/2AP13XC) and [/dev/sdb](http://dpaste.com/34B99HV). Apparently, there is a *protective MBR* and a *damaged GPT* partitions table.

I found [this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/644902/gpt-disk-partition-recovery?rq=1) that seemed fit with our issue. Unfortunately, the Host Protected Area is disabled and thus is not the problem.

I can't figure out what to do or investigate now.

Here is a bit more information about /dev/sda GPT issues: http://dpaste.com/3K25Z1Z

Pasted commands were executed over sysrescuecd. Windows 8.1 does not encounter issues with the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PC was sold as embedding a 120 Go SSD, but actually embedded 2 60Go SSDs in RAID-0...